# Mysql update и массив

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется запрос:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `position` = ? WHERE `id` = ?
```

Еще имеется массив, id => position:

```
$replace = array(1 =>0, 5 => 1, 7 => 2);
```

И мне нужно обновить столько полей в таблице, сколько содержится элементов в массиве.
Можно, но не нужно, проделать это в цикле, результат будет верным, но реализация паршива.

Вопрос:
как можно составить запрос к базе, чтобы получить правильный результат?

Comment: У каждого id свой position? Или он один для всех id?

Comment: У каждого id свой position.
id|position
1 |0
5 |1
7 |2
3 |3
2 |4
4 |5
6 |6

Comment: Я не про базу спрашиваю, а про обновление: у всех id из массива после обновления будет один и тот же position? Если так, то почему бы не заменить `WHERE id = ?` на `WHERE id IN (?)`, а массив подставлять как `implode(',', $id)`

Comment: Я не про базу отвечаю, а про обновление :) Это то, что получится после правильного обновления

Comment: Ну здесь, наверное, проще будет через INSERT:

    INSERT INTO table (id, position)
    VALUES (1, 0), (5, 1)...
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE position = VALUES(position)

Как-то так. А строку `(1, 0), (5, 1)...` построить несложно (самое простое - через тот же цикл)

Comment: Да, работает, спасибо! Осталось только теперь как-то вручную обрабатывать приходящие данные :)

Answer (score 2):

> Можно, но не нужно, проделать это в цикле, результат будет верным, но
>   реализация паршива.

Всё **ровно наоборот.** Можно, но ни в коем случае не стоит это делать одним запросом.

Если нам надо обновить 10 записей, то надо сделать 10 запросов. Это азбука работы с БД. Никакой проблемы выполнить 10 запросов нету.

Но зато есть **проблема с использованием неверного инструмента для этой цели.** Запрос `INSERT INTO`, который посоветовали в комментах - он, вообще-то, если кто не заметил - на ВСТАВКУ. А не на обновление. А это значит, что он ВСТАВЛЯЕТ записи. И - будте уверены - ВСТАВИТ. Запись, которая уже была удалена. Если 10 запросов на обновление найдут только 9 подходящих записей, то обновят только 9 записей. А запрос на вставку обновит 9, а потом вставит еще одну.

То есть `INSERT INTO` c `ON DUPLICATE` - это не красивая замена 10 запросам `UPDATE`, а **совершенно другой запрос.**

Судя по знакам вопроса в запросе,  у автора уже используются подготовленные выражения. то есть механизм - СПЕЦИАЛЬНО придуманный для множественного запроса. И остается только написать простой код

```
$replace = array(1 =>0, 5 => 1);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `table` SET `position` = ? WHERE `id` = ?");
foreach ($replace as $id -> $position)
{
    $stmt->execute(array($position, $id));
}
```

И впредь любые инструменты использовать строго по назначению.

Comment: в данном случае будет правильнее использовать конструкцию in
    UPDATE `table` SET `position` = ? WHERE `id` in (......) (не знаю как это будет выглядеть на php) т.к. идёт вставка одного значения в несколько записей. предварительно преобразовав массив в строку с разделителем

Answer (score 2):

В вопросе не сказано приходят ли эти данные от пользователя, поэтому вот так по простому без экранирования:

```
foreach ($replace as $k => v) {
  $values[] = "({$k}, {$v})";
}
$str = join(',', $values);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table`(`id`, `position`) VALUES
       {$str}
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
       `id`=VALUES(`id`), `position`=VALUES(`position`)";
```